# Do sharing rules have impact on Automated Process user?

Tags: sharing-rule, automated-process

Due to the critical updates that will impact guest users, I have to do a rework on some apex classes and triggers that assigns the ownership to the guest user. To overcome this problem, the new owner is Automated Process, but it seems that the sharing rule don't share records that belong to Automated Process User.

I didn't find any that report this excepet for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ksxhAAA) that refers to a report to records created by Automated Process.

What do you think about that?

Comment: see this [q&a for the historical background](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325736/criteria-based-sharing-rules-dont-work-when-record-is-owned-by-automated-proces/325737#325737)

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed via [an enhancement in Spring '22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_hvu_or_system_user_records_in_criteria_based_sharing_rules.htm&type=5&release=236) that lets you opt users like Automated Process User into sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The sharing rule in place will not share records (owned by the "Automated Process" user).

Please find below the Idea raised on this.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lFGpQAM