# Criteria-based sharing rules don't work when record is owned by Automated Process User

Tags: criteria-based-sharing, automated-process

I have an OWD of PRIVATE on Account/Contact

- Criteria-based sharing rule extends Read to users in Group `MyGroup`

Given a user

- with CRUD `R` on Account but not `View ALL` or `View All Data`
- member of `MyGroup`

When search is done by said user...

- Record **is not found** if owned by `Automated Process` user
- Record **is found** if owned by any other user

What's going on?

*(Implications for consumers of Platform Events that don't coerce an ownerId on inserted records)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YodtQAC)

When you click the **Sharing** button

- On a record owned by Automated Process, you see one entry for `License Manager`. Expanding `License Manager` you get all the users with `View All` on the Account object
- On a record owned by any other user, you see an entry for `User` (the owner), and for `MyGroup` - that is, as expected.

**Workarounds**:

- use triggers or other automation to change the owner of the record to other than Automated Process  *or ...*
- extend View All permissions on record's SObject to affected users

**UPDATE:**
[Issue resolved in Spring 22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_hvu_or_system_user_records_in_criteria_based_sharing_rules.htm&type=5&release=236)

Comment: Agreed. I would add, perhaps the process / flow / trigger on your Platform Event could be explicitly set to assign a default owner. If you don't want to hard-code an ID you could use something like `Organization.WebToCaseDefaultCreatorId`.